# Trying to run a snippet implementing react-router-dom routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to run this snippet here on SO.

I'm using `react-router-dom` from CDN. I'm able to match the first route but somehow I can't change to a different route.

Is it possible to simulate routing like this using the snippet? This same scrips works on jsFiddle.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
const { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

function App() {
 
  return(
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/js" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/js/comp1" component={Component1}/>
     </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Home...');
 return(
    <React.Fragment>
     <div>I am home</div>
      
      <div>props.location.pathname: {props.location.pathname}</div>
      <div>props.match.path: {props.match.path}</div>
      
      <Link to='/js/comp1'>Component1</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Component1(props) {
  console.log('Rendering Component1...');
 return(
    <React.Fragment>
     <div>I am Component1</div>
      
      <div>props.location.pathname: {props.location.pathname}</div>
      <div>props.match.path: {props.match.path}</div>
      
      <Link to='/js'>Home</Link>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.0.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: when you say you can't match the other route, is it using your `<Link>` component in `Home` and by typing in the url aswell ?

Comment: Using the link. It's not possible to type a URL inside the snippet iframe.

Comment: You don't have the app running in your local browser?

Comment: No, in my local environment this works just fine. But I was trying to get it run inside the snippet here on SO. The same way it works inside jsFiddle.net, where you also don't have a URL to type.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-kgdly?from-embed i've managed to make it run there as well, but with code snippet doesn't seem to work, i might be a limitation

Comment: It might be. I also asked this on StackOverflow Meta, but no answer so far. Thanks!

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to run it as a code snippet ? seems strange to me lol

Comment: I always try to make an example with minimal functionality to illustrate my problems. The snippet is as minimal as I can get. Also, the CodeSandbox links might no longer be available at some point. And I'm always asking questions about client-side routing with react-router. And since I saw that this is possible in jsFiddle, I thought I could do it here also.